# Merge JS sub-objects into a JS object with joined keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing template software for publishing node.js modules to GitHub and NPM. A small snippet of an example template:

> ## {{module.name}}
>
> ### {{module.description}}
>
> ### Purpose
>
> {{module.code.purpose}}

I have an object built up with all these properties, ex.

```
{
  "module" : {
    "name" : "test",
    "description" : "Test module"
...
```

The problem is that I need to merge this object's sub-objects so the final output looks something like this (for replacing the placeholders in the templates):

```
{
  "module.name" : "test",
  "module.description" : "Test module"
...
```

So I created my own function to do that:

```
/**
    Takes an object like
    {
        "type" : "meal",
        "pizza" : {
            "toppings" : ["pepperoni", "cheese"],
            "radius" : 6,
            "metadata" : {
                "id" : 24553
            }
        }
    }
    and changes it to
    {
        "type" : "meal",
        "pizza.toppings" : ["pepperoni", "cheese"],
        "pizza.radius" : 6,
        "pizza.metadata.id" : 244553
    }
*/
const mergeObjectsToKeys = object => {

    // Loop through the passed in object's properties

    return Object.entries(object).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {

        // Check if it is a sub-object or not

        if (typeof value === "object") {

            // If it is a sub-object, merge its properties with recursion and then put those keys into the master object

            const subObject = mergeObjectsToKeys(value);

            Object.entries(subObject).forEach(([key2, value2]) => {
                obj[key + "." + key2] = value2;
            });
        } else {

            // Otherwise, just put the key into the object to return

            obj[key] = value;
        }
    }, { });
};
```

## Two questions

- Is this the correct way to write the software?
- If so, is there a **built-in** function to merge the sub-objects, like shown above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand _why_ you're trying to redefine objects in this way.

Comment: You need to return `obj` at the end, I think. Recursion is a reasonable solution for this problem, and I'm not aware of a core JS method that flattens objects in precisely this way. Underscore has a method for flattening arrays.

Comment: @SMcCrohan Okay, thanks. I was just wondering if there was a core JS method. Also, I forgot to return `obj` at the end because I forgot to copy and paste that line.

Comment: You could remove the need to declare and return `obj` by using `reduce` instead of `forEach`, if you wanted to.

Comment: @m_callens The reason I'm trying to redefine the objects in this way is so that I can target the template. I need to replace `{{module.name}}` in the template with `someObject.module.name`. So if I converted the object, I could write something like this: `Object.entries(convertedObject).forEach(([key, value]) => { template.replace("{{" + key + "}}", value) });`

Comment: @SMcCrohan I like that idea. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One built-in function to handle the requirement is `Object.assign()`; you can use spread element, `Object.entries()`, `.map()` to set property names of object which is property of object.

To handler objects where value is not nested object

```
let p = Object.keys(o).pop();
let res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(o.module).map(([key, prop]) =>
            ({[`${p}.${key}`]: prop})));
```

To handle value which is nested object

```js
let o = {
  "type": "meal",
  "pizza": {
    "toppings": ["pepperoni", "cheese"],
    "radius": 6,
    "metadata": {
      "id": 24553
    }
  }
}

let res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(o).map(([prop, value]) => 
            typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value) 
            ? Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(value)
              .map(([key,val]) => ({[`${prop}.${key}`]: key})))
            : {[prop]: value})
          );

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Gives me a `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: The approach is not recursive itself. Tried at `module` example https://jsfiddle.net/oadfw5mh/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (I have other objects, ex. `license.name` and `copyright.holder`), but this could solve someone else's problem (it also doesn't go deep enough, which isn't a problem for me, but I want it to go as deep as possible for scalability).

Comment: @Bennett Including `.filter()` as second parameter to `Object.assign()` to match and include objects where value of property is not object, given second example at OP https://jsfiddle.net/oadfw5mh/1/